# Any program with Selenium throws an error

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Any program with Selenium throws an error like:

```
/home/dibusure/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:108:in `new_request_for': uninitialized constant Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default::Net (NameError)

            req = Net::HTTP.const_get(verb.to_s.capitalize).new(url.path, headers)
                  ^^^
Did you mean?  Set
    from /home/dibusure/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:74:in `request'
    from /home/dibusure/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    from /home/dibusure/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:620:in `execute'
    from /home/dibusure/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:53:in `create_session'
    from /home/dibusure/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:317:in `block in create_bridge'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /home/dibusure/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:316:in `create_bridge'
    from /home/dibusure/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:74:in `initialize'
    from /home/dibusure/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/driver.rb:43:in `initialize'
    from /home/dibusure/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:53:in `new'
    from /home/dibusure/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:53:in `for'
    from /home/dibusure/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:88:in `for'
    from main.rb:13:in `initialize_driver'
    from main.rb:6:in `initialize'
    from main.rb:54:in `new'
    from main.rb:54:in `<main>'
```

Gecko and selenium installed by bundle, my system is nixos

tried kubuntu and nixos, tried chromedriver
expected selenium launch

Comment: You need to show some piece of code that causes the error or no one will be able to help you.